# ¿Como envolver mi código en una instrucción USING?

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día,

Utilizo el siguiente código para llenar un combobox, vengo tomando un proyecto de un antiguo programador que no realizaba buen uso de "las buenas practicas", en mi caso, me gusta apegarme a ellas, por lo cual, quisiera saber como envolver el siguiente código en una instrucción USING para eliminar aquel codigo innecesario y dejar que mi aplicación haga trabajo.

```
            cls_general myCls_general = new cls_general();

        myCls_general.conexion_mssql("1");

        strSQL = "SELECT [IdContacto],[fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social] FROM OTROS_CONFIG.dbo.vi_list_contactos WHERE [IdContacto] <> @contacto_id " +
            "ORDER BY [fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social] ASC";

        myCboReferentesDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myCls_general.myConnection);
        myCboReferentesDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contacto_id", txt_cod_contacto.Text);
        myCboReferentesDataSet = new DataSet();
        myCboReferentesDataAdapter.Fill(myCboReferentesDataSet, "vi_list_contactos");

        cbo_contacto_referente.Properties.DataSource = myCboReferentesDataSet.Tables["vi_list_contactos"];
        cbo_contacto_referente.Properties.DisplayMember = "fld_Nomb_Apel_Razon_Social";
        cbo_contacto_referente.Properties.ValueMember = "IdContacto";

        myCboReferentesDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        myCboReferentesDataAdapter.Dispose();
        myCboReferentesDataSet.Dispose();
        myCls_general.cerrar_conexion();
```

Actualmente no utilizo mi clase "cls_general" para traer la cadena de conexión, ya que ahora almaceno dicha cadena en la configuración de mi aplicación, lo que me interesa aprender, ¿es cuando debo anidar las instrucciones using en un código?

Es esta la mejor forma de cargar un combobox? Que puedo mejorar? Está correcta la forma de utilizar USING para que limpie los objectos y cierre la conexión?

```
using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.OTROS))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            string sqlquery = "SELECT [rubro_id],[rubro] FROM BienesDeUsoRubros ORDER BY[rubro] ASC";

            using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    lookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "rubro_id";
                    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "rubro";
                    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: En primer lugar, ¿tienes claro lo que hace un using? Veo `.Dispose()` y `cerrar_conexion` Por otro lado, ¿qué código crees que es innecesario?

Comment: Buen día, como te va? Si, se que Using hace el manejo del dispose y a su vez del Close de la conexión, por lo tanto, estoy refactorizando este código que tiene malas practicas de programación, lo que no se, es como anidar los using para que elimine correctamente cada objecto usado.

El código que muestro es el actual, lo que necesitaria es un ejemplo en base a ese código de como hacer uso correcto del USING.

Comment: Regular hermano, hay mantenimiento del techo del departamento donde vivo y todo el santo día andan con martillos, taladros, hasta creo que los encargados están bailando x.x, al margen de eso, todo fresh. Ah perfecto! entonces sí conoces cómo es el asunto, deja te publico un ejemplo en ese caso :D

Comment: Jajajaja, excelente respuesta! Vale, te molesto mucho si me ayudas a armarlo en base al código que publico en la pregunta? Soy nuevo con esto y me apoyo en ustedes para mejorar tanto a manera personal, como el aplicativo que tengo a cargo.

Esa es la mejor forma de llenar un combobox? En base a ese código, que debo anidar en los using? 

Primero la conexión: 

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.Otros))

Luego el dataapdater, luego el dataset?

Si cargaras un combobox con datos en tu app, que metodos usas que sean el mas eficiente.

Comment: Vale, entonces edita la pregunta, coloca más código y algún pantallazo de lo que quieres lograr, entre más datos hayan, más chance de obtener una mejor respuesta :D

Comment: Si, ya lo hago en base a más o menos creer como se hace, pero te consulto a manera personal, esa es la mejor forma de cargar un combobox? O hay una forma más optima y limpia?

Comment: Para eso es la comunidad, no? Creo que enriquece aprender de otros, el que no quiera responder, salta la pregunta y listo. Si vas a clases y no entiendes el texto, tienes al profesor que te explica, no? Es la forma de como veo la comunidad, créeme que paso horas leyendo, pero al ser nuevo, hay cosas que no entiendo.

Comment: Gracias lobos! Claramente no todos nacen entendidos como tu persona. No soy "flojo" ni mucho menos espero soluciones mágicas de la gente en la red. Soy desenfrenado en aprender "buenas practicas" y por ende pregunto tanto. Ya que sabes tanto, si googleas un poco en la web, te encontraras mil formas, algunas de ellas hasta en la misma web oficial de microsoft que van para adelante y para atrás en su propio código. Por eso busco preguntar mucho, para aprender de gente con experiencia en el rubro, así como en algún momento tu también hayas tenido dudas que resolver a lo largo de tu carrera.

Comment: bro, encuéntrame en la sala de chat de SOes https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol Twitter o en Telegram con el mismo nick "fredyfx" para poder guiarte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de múltiple `using`:

```
using (var sr = new StringReader(content))
using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
{
    obj = XmlSerializer.Deserialize(xtr) as TModel;
}
```

Extraído de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396092/3613462

Documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement